# emmeans contrasts of linear slope

Tags: r, regression, lsmeans

I apologise for no doubt a basic question that I am having difficulty intuiting. I have data with a time component that is measured at irregular intervals (but the same irregular intervals for everyone). In analysing this I could consider time as categorical (which I would normally do) but I have started using splines a little more, so am beginning to explore treating time more as continuous. As it turns out in this case, constraining the 'effect' of time to be linear fits better than using a spline.

My question is, why does emmeans give the same p value for every contrast of time - even though the magnitude of the estimates can be quite different? This is the p value for the slope, right (i.e. the same as the coefficient in the model), so is it a case that it doesn't matter what times you compare if you are treating time as linear, the p value is constrained to be the same?

Am I correct in thinking the only way to obtain contrasts that may differ in statistical significance is to freely estimate the adjusted outcome means by treating time as categorical?

Thanks.

```
> emmeans(mod, ~ time, at = list(time = c(0, 1, 6, 12))) |>   
+   regrid() |> pairs(reverse = T, adjust = "none") |> 
+   summary(infer = T)
 contrast       estimate      SE   df lower.CL upper.CL t.ratio p.value
 time1 - time0  -0.00565 0.00925 30.1  -0.0245   0.0132  -0.611  0.5458
 time6 - time0  -0.03390 0.05548 30.0  -0.1472   0.0794  -0.611  0.5458
 time6 - time1  -0.02825 0.04623 30.0  -0.1227   0.0662  -0.611  0.5458
 time12 - time0 -0.06779 0.11096 30.3  -0.2943   0.1587  -0.611  0.5458
 time12 - time1 -0.06214 0.10171 30.1  -0.2698   0.1455  -0.611  0.5458
 time12 - time6 -0.03390 0.05548 30.0  -0.1472   0.0794  -0.611  0.5458
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your model, you've specified that the effect of time on the outcome is a linear function of time. It isn't the case that the creators of emmeans have constrained the p.value to be the same. The results follow from the fact that you have specified a linear effect in time.

I will outline below: for illustrative purposes, it is sufficient to treat the estimated coefficients as having an approximate normal distribution under the null since a $t_{30}$ is close to normal.

$$
\beta\sim N(\mu,\sigma^2)\rightarrow a\beta\sim N(a\mu,a^2\sigma^2)
$$

In your contrasts, you specify the contrasts of times, which has the following distribution.

$$
\beta_T 12 -\beta_T 1 \rightarrow 11\beta_T\sim N(11\mu,11^2\sigma^2)
$$

This will then lead to another normal distribution which is tested under a $N(0,1)$ null:

$$
\Delta_{12,1}\sim N(11\mu,11\sigma^2)\rightarrow \frac{11\mu}{\sqrt{11^2\sigma^2}}\ \sim N(0,1)
$$

In general, you are going to have:

$$
\Delta_{T_F,T_O}\sim N(\Delta_T\mu,(\Delta_T^2)\sigma^2)\rightarrow \frac{\Delta_T\mu}{\Delta_T\sigma}\sim N(0,1)
$$

From this it is clear, the differences only depend on the gap between the time intervals, and second, the test statistic will always be $\mu/\sigma$, which is what was used to compute the p-value in the original regression. The standard errors will change by some multiple of the gap in time. This can all be observed in the $T_6-T_0$ and $T_{12}-T_6$ results.

If it is the case that a linear form is better for the data, then so be it. You might not have enough data to estimate the differences in the time points themselves if you treated the time points as categorical predictors. I would not focus on trying to obtain significant results by further breaking down the data ... if you have *substantive* reason to believe that the linear relation does not hold between time points of your data, then it might be worth pursuing your idea of computing regressions in between each group.